# How do you make gccgo compile pig.go?

Tags: go

There is a file pig.go on the golang.org website:

```
    http://golang.org/doc/codewalk/functions/ 
    in a box labeled doc/codewalk/pig.go
```

Compiling it with gccgo version (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1

```
    gccgo pig.go
```

gives an error message about not finding math/rand

```
    pig.go:9:11: error: import file ‘math/rand’ not found
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your version of gccgo implements an old version of the language. To compile Go 1 code, you need gccgo 4.7.1 or later.

If you can't or don't want to upgrade, you could probably just change the import from `math/rand` to `rand` and it will compile with gccgo 4.6.1. Not all programs will be so easy to backport, but this one happens to be.

Comment: Thanks Evan! With just "rand" and not "math/rand" it compiles and runs fine.